# PouchDB growing with revisions even when revs_limit: 1

Tags: pouchdb

I've created PouchDB with the option not to create revisions

```
var db = new PouchDB('test1', {
  revs_limit: 1,
  auto_compaction: true
});
```

When I inspect indexedDB in chrome it looks like revisions are stored there. I'd like to keep size of db small as it is used in cordova project, no sync with CouchDB is needed.

PouchDB.version === "5.3.2".
It a bug in PouchDB or did I missed smth?

The following code demonstrates how revisions are created: 
[image]

```
function upsert(id, title) {
  var obj;

  return db.get(id)
    .then(function (doc) {
      obj = { // UPDATE
        _id: id,
        _rev: doc._rev,
        title: title
      };
      return db.put(obj)
        .then(function (res) {
          console.log('updated', res);
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
          console.error('update error', obj, e);
        });
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      if (e.status === 404) {
        obj = { // INSERT
          _id: id,
          title: title
        };
        return db.put(obj)
          .then(function (res) {
            console.log('inserted', res);
          })
          .catch(function (e) {
            console.error('insert error', obj, e);
          });
      }
      console.error('another error', e);
    });
}

var db = new PouchDB('test1', {
  revs_limit: 1,
  auto_compaction: true
});
var id = '666-' + (new Date()).toISOString();
var serializer;
console.log('Test started with\nid = ' + id);
db.then(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (!serializer) {
      serializer = upsert(id, 'Heroes');
    } else {
      serializer = serializer
        .then(function () {
          return upsert(id, 'Heroes')
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you try clicking "refresh IndexedDB" to ensure that it's up to date? If so, it does sound like a bug in PouchDB.

Comment: Might be this bug: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/4372

Comment: I clicked on "refresh IndexedDB", data is there.

Comment: Sounds like a bug then...

Comment: The following info on https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/4372
solved my problem. Thanks.

As a workaround it looks like everything is fine with revs_limits: 1 only, if revs_limit is 1 then auto_compaction isnt needed anyway

Comment: @MiloslavSkacel @nlawson I see the same problem in Chrome even when using `{revs_limt: 1}` in options. Every time I reload the page and update the doc, the chrome shows IndexDB size increasing. This doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this was [a closed bug](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/4372) partly fixed in Feb 2016, then fully fixed in Jun 2016.

Using `auto_compaction: true` is redundant when setting `revs_limit:1` (as there would never be anything to compact).  (Using the two together used to trigger a bug, but it was fixed in 2016.)

As described at the bottom of [another closed bug report](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/7100), Chrome will look like memory is growing, even when you use `revs_limit` or `auto_compaction`. But when you reach 4MB, then it will do the compaction in one go. This is by design, so is not a bug in pouchDB and not a bug in Chrome.

(Just thought I'd answer to save the next person the 15 minutes it took to work through the discussions!)